# Regex: Extract string between [..]

Tags: python, regex

Exmaple: "[A]_AND_[B]_AND_[C]3NOT[C]_AND_NOT__[D]__AND_[E]13[F]_AND_[G]_AND_NOT[G]"

>> [A,B,C,C,D,E,F,G,G]

I want to extract every sub-string within [ ]. Couldn't figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: What did you try? Did you escape the `[]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
source="[A]_AND_[B]_AND_[C]3NOT[C]_AND_NOT__[D]__AND_[E]13[F]_AND_[G]_AND_NOT[G]"
regex=r"\[(\w*)\]"
ans=re.findall(regex,source)
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do it without regex.

```
o = []
for i in range(len(s)-2):
    ns = s[i:i+3]
    if ns[0] == '[' and ns[2] == ']':
        o.append(ns[1])
o
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract any **sub-string** in square-bracket, You could use the regex pattern:
`\[([^\[\]\r\n])\]`

```
import re

source="[A]_AND_[B]_AND_[C]3NOT[C]_AND_NOT__[D]__AND_[E]13[F]_AND_[G]_AND_NOT[G]"
regexPattern=r"\[([^\[\]\r\n])\]"

result=re.findall(regexPattern,source)
print('['+ (','.join(result)) + ']')
```

**Explanation:**

- `\[` is the first character of the expression that matches `[`.
- `([^\[\]\r\n])` is a group that match any character excepts `\r: carriage return` `\n: end of line` `[` `]`.
- `\]` is the last character of the expression that matches `]`.
- `findall()` function returns a list containing all matched-groups.

See https://regex101.com/r/ZCitXv/1